# Why does adding DWG from AutoCAD Civil 3D 2012 freeze ArcMap 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, autocad, dwg

I use AutoCAD Civil 3D 2012 and ArcMap 10.1.

I am trying to add a .dwg file into ArcMap and no matter how I try (drag and drop from Catalog window, Add Data) ArcMap freezes and locks up.

Any ideas?

Comment: in AutoCAD you can save as a lower .dwg version (2000) that should load in ArcMap. 2012 has some new 3d elements that arcmap cannot interpret.

Comment: Make sure the dwg isn't open in AutoCAD before trying to open in it ArcGIS.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Though I use Civil 3D there are no actual 3D elements in the dwg. I have saved it down to 2000 and made sure the drawing is closed yet it still freezes.

Comment: some tips with CAD file at ArcGIS 10.1 http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00100000002r000000

Comment: Does this happen every time you try or just frequently?  Does the freeze require you to close ArcMap or does it eventually come back? What version of Windows are you using? Please edit these details into your Question.